# mutate_at with all_of() in r?

Tags: r, debugging, deprecation-warning, tidyselect

Trying to future proof some code here. I was unable to figure out this following warning message:

```
snpdata <- snpdata %>%
  mutate_at(vars(snpcol_start:snpcol_end),
            list(~ ifelse(. == 0, "AA", ifelse(. == 1, "AB", .))))
```

> Warning messages:
> 1: Using an external vector in selections was deprecated in tidyselect >1.1.0.
> ℹ Please use `all_of()` or `any_of()` instead.
>
> # Was:
> data %>% select(snpcol_start)
>
> # Now:
> data %>% select(all_of(snpcol_start))
>
> See https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/faq-external-vector.html.
> This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
>
> Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was generated.
> 2: Using an external vector in selections was deprecated in tidyselect 1.1.0.
> ℹ Please use `all_of()` or `any_of()` instead.
>
> # Was:
> data %>% select(snpcol_end)
>
> # Now:
> data %>% select(all_of(snpcol_end))
>
> See https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/faq-external-vector.html.
> This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
> Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was generated.

Please help, I am new to R

Comment: I believe the 'up-to-date' syntax would be `snpdata <- snpdata %>% mutate(across(snpcol_start:snpcol_end, ~ifelse(.x == 0, "AA", ifelse(.x == 1, "AB", .x))))`, but I can't test it without a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so you'll have to check if that gives you the same outcome yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `across`, not `all_of`.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(
  library(dplyr)
)

set.seed(2023)
snpdata <- replicate(3, rbinom(5, 1, 0.5)) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  `names<-`(paste("snpcol", c("start", "mid", "end"), sep = "_"))

snpdata %>%
  mutate_at(vars(snpcol_start:snpcol_end),
            list(~ ifelse(. == 0, "AA", ifelse(. == 1, "AB", .))))
#>   snpcol_start snpcol_mid snpcol_end
#> 1           AA         AA         AB
#> 2           AA         AA         AA
#> 3           AA         AB         AA
#> 4           AA         AA         AB
#> 5           AA         AA         AB

snpdata %>%
  mutate(across(snpcol_start:snpcol_end,
                ~ ifelse(. == 0, "AA", ifelse(. == 1, "AB", .))))
#>   snpcol_start snpcol_mid snpcol_end
#> 1           AA         AA         AB
#> 2           AA         AA         AA
#> 3           AA         AB         AA
#> 4           AA         AA         AB
#> 5           AA         AA         AB
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

A `across/case_when` solution is

```r
snpdata %>%
  mutate(across(snpcol_start:snpcol_end,
                ~ case_when(
                  . == 0 ~ "AA",
                  . == 1 ~ "BB",
                  TRUE ~ as.character(.)
                )))
#>   snpcol_start snpcol_mid snpcol_end
#> 1           AA         AA         BB
#> 2           AA         AA         AA
#> 3           AA         BB         AA
#> 4           AA         AA         BB
#> 5           AA         AA         BB
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The new syntax is this:

```
# sample data
snpdata <- tibble(
    snpcol_start = c(1, 0, 1),
    snpcol_end = c(0, 1, 0)
)

snpdata %>%
  mutate(across(snpcol_start:snpcol_end, \(x) ifelse(x == 0, "AA", ifelse(x == 1, "AB", x))))
```

I've swapped out the tilde syntax for anonymous functions for the `\(x)` syntax introduced in R 4.1. You can also, if you want things to be more concise (and readable), replace the nested `ifelse` with a `case_when`:

```
snpdata %>%
  mutate(across(snpcol_start:snpcol_end, \(x) case_when(
    x == 0 ~ "AA",
    x == 1 ~ "AB",
    TRUE ~ as.character(x)
  )))
```